# how to change device id of thrust::device_vector

Tags: cuda, thrust

is it possible to change the device id of thrust::device vector?
I'm thinking to code like this

```
cudaSetDevice(0);                                //set to device:0
thrust::device_vector<int> a(10);                //define the device vector
a.clear(); thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(a); //deallocate the vector

cudaSetDevice(1);                                //set to device:1
a.resize(10);
```

is it possible?
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289860/multiple-gpus-with-cuda-thrust

Comment: In your code snippet, you are freeing `a` (see [how to free device_vector<int>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113899/how-to-free-device-vectorint)) and after that you are resizing it on device `1`?

Comment: @PhillipD it didn't tell how to change device of a vector container

Comment: @JackOLantern yes, i did freeing the memory by doing thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a correct answer. so please correct me if I'm wrong because i don't whether the test is proper enough. So I decided to do test on vector addition as follows

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const int *A, const int *B, int *C, int numElements) {
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < numElements) C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
};

int main(void)
{
    int numElements = 1024;
    int randacc = 30;

    cudaSetDevice(0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> a(numElements, 1);
    thrust::device_vector<int> b(numElements, 2);
    thrust::device_vector<int> c(numElements);

    int* a_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&a[0]);
    int* b_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&b[0]);
    int* c_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&c[0]);

    int threadsPerBlock = 64;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(a_d, b_d, c_d, numElements);
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "random access on dev 0, c = " << c[randacc] << std::endl;

    a.clear(); thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(a); //deallocate the vector
    b.clear(); thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(b); //deallocate the vector
    c.clear(); thrust::device_vector<int>().swap(c); //deallocate the vector

    cudaSetDevice(1);                                //set to device:1
    a.resize(numElements, 1);
    b.resize(numElements, 2);
    c.resize(numElements);

    a_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&a[0]);
    b_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&b[0]);
    c_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&c[0]);

    threadsPerBlock = 64;
    blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(a_d, b_d, c_d, numElements);
    err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cerr << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "random access on dev 1, c = " << c[randacc] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and I get result:

> random access on dev 0, c = 3
>
> random access on dev 1, c = 3

Note: you need at least 2 GPUs on the same host to test it. i tested on my GTX690

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if and how it works exactly with thrust and if you tried to change the device id of a device array not using thrust and if you are aware of peer-to-peer memory access.

It is an interesting question but I can do my own experiments.
However, according to the CUDA Programming Guide (section 3.2.6.4) peer-to-peer memory access is possible (i.e. two devices can address each other's memory) if you use **compute capability 2.x** and above using **Tesla cards**.

This is an example from the Programming Guide:

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
float* p0;
size_t size = 1024 * sizeof(float);
cudaMalloc(&p0, size);
MyKernel<<<1000, 128>>>(p0);
cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaDeviceEnablePeerAccess(0, 0);  // <- this enables peer to peer access
MyKernel<<<1000,128>>>(p0);
```

Concerning memory copy from one device to another, the Programming Guide says that cudaMemcpyPeer() can do the job and provides an example. 
I can not find something in the thrust documentation that corresponds to your question, so I think the best way is to try it.

Comment: Last sentence is enough for this answer.

Comment: @PhillipD even though it is related to peer-to-peer, but my question is not about peer-to-peer because what I want to do is that mimicking this process: set the memory on device 0, free the memory, with the same pointer set the memory on device 1. But, instead using normal cudaMalloc, i want to do it using thrust::device_vector